# How to correctly build optimized (faster builds) for Nextjs production image using Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js

I have struggled to find good examples of images in Nextjs for docker images. The images I have found have not suited my needs. Below is the current image that I am using currently. I am trying to speed it up, I think a way in where I dont have to install twice would be more ideal.

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:14.8.0-alpine3.12 AS deps

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN apk add git
RUN npm install 
RUN mkdir /app/.next


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:14.8.0-alpine3.12 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN npm run build && npm install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:14.8.0-alpine3.12 AS runner
WORKDIR /app

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/.env.production ./


USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Doing install twice let's subsequent docker builds run faster as long as you haven't changed `package,json`, since Docker can use a cached version of the image.

Comment: I'd probably `npm run build` in the same Docker build stage where you first run `npm install`, including the `devDependencies`; the second stage can then use `npm install --production` to get a reduced runtime-only `node_modules` tree.  Don't forget to copy the `package-lock.json` file (in both stages) to get a consistent set of packages.